# Mini-Max Sum HACKERHANK JS, why isn't working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I don't know what's wrong, my function miniMaxSum isn't summing 1+3+4+5. At the end, the result array turns into this [ 14, 12, 11, 10 ], when it should looks like this [ 14, **13**, 12, 11, 10 ]

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
  let results = [];
  let actualValue = 0;
  let skipIndex = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //skip actual index
    if (i == skipIndex) continue;
    actualValue += arr[i];

    //restart the loop
    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
      skipIndex++;
      results.push(actualValue);
      actualValue = 0;
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  console.log(results);
  console.log(Math.min(...results), Math.max(...results));
}

console.log(miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: What logic is that function meant to be implementing? Can you explain in English how the desired result is produced from the input?

Comment: This translates to "my program doesn't do something". We're really not sure why that output would be valid. What are the rules here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-complicating your algorithm by trying to check whether you should add the current number to the overall sum or not. Instead, all you need to do is run a loop over your array, to sum up all your elements in your array. This will give you the total sum of all your elements. Then, again, iterate through your array. For each element in your array subtract it from the sum you just calculated and push it into a new array. This will give you the sum if you were to not use the number in the `ith` position. You can then find the min/max of this using JavaScript's `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions.

Here is an example using `.reduce()` and `.map()` to calculate the final result:

```js
const miniMaxSum = arr => {
  const sum = arr.reduce((s, n) => n+s, 0)
  const results = arr.map(n => sum - n);
  return [Math.min(...results), Math.max(...results)];
}

const [min, max] = miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(min, max);
```

If you prefer standard for loops, here is an implementation of the above in a more imperative style:

```js
const miniMaxSum = arr => {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // sum all elements
    sum += arr[i];
  }
  
  let results = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    results[i] = sum - arr[i]; // sum minus the current number
  }
  return [Math.min(...results), Math.max(...results)];
}

const [min, max] = miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(min, max);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you're talking about [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum/problem) question.

Whenever you want to restart the loop, you're setting `i=0` but observe that you also have increment statement `i++` in `for` loop so, effectively `i` starts from `1`, not `0`. You need to set `i=-1` so that `i=-1+1 = 0` in subsequent iteration. After doing this, you need to handle a corner case. When `skipIndex==arr.length-1`, check if `i == arr.length-1`. If yes, do `results.push(actualValue);` for the last value and then `for` loop terminates because `i < arr.length` is `false` in next iteration.

---

Code:

```js
function miniMaxSum(arr) {
let results = [];
let actualValue = 0;
let skipIndex = 0;
  
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //skip actual index
    if (i == skipIndex){
        if(i == arr.length - 1)
            results.push(actualValue);
        continue;
    }
    actualValue += arr[i];

    //restart the loop
    if (i == arr.length - 1) {
        skipIndex++;
        results.push(actualValue);
        actualValue = 0;
        i = -1;
    }
}
console.log(results);
console.log(Math.min(...results), Math.max(...results));
}

miniMaxSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

---

Output

```js
[ 14, 13, 12, 11, 10 ]
10 14
```